# is UI Thread in process's thread pool in android?

Tags: android, multithreading

As documentation said, each process has a thread pool for itself. so, is UI Thread in that pool?

"Note that IPC calls are dispatched through a thread pool running in each process, so the code executing here will NOT be running in our main thread like most other things -- so, to update the UI, we need to use a Handler to hop over there." -aidl documentation

why it said "will Not be running in our main thread"  and didn't say "may not"? is that because UI Thread is not in the process's thread pool?

Answer (score 0):

> is that because UI Thread is not in the process's thread pool?

Correct. The main application thread ("UI thread") is not part of the process' AIDL/IPC thread pool.

Comment: why?  can you tell me how did you find this note?

Comment: documentation said: "Incoming calls are not guaranteed to be executed on the main thread, so you need to think about multithreading from the start and properly build your service to be thread-safe."  - aidl.    so it is only about service's main thread?